# Difference between generating UUID in Java and MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, uuid

I need to insert random id into one table and add that id to another table as foreign key. So I am not sure how to save UUID() if I generated it in MySQL but if I generate it in Java I can just save it into a variable. I wonder are there any drawbacks if I generate it in Java?

Thanks

Comment: no no draw backs

Comment: I would use auto increment for ID.  When  you insert, you can request for the last inserted ID.

Comment: When in doubt, read [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier). To quote: *[UUIDs’] uniqueness does not depend on a central registration authority or coordination between the parties generating them, unlike most other numbering schemes. … Thus, anyone can create a UUID and use it to identify something with near certainty that the identifier does not duplicate one that has already been, or will be, created to identify something else. Information labeled with UUIDs by independent parties can therefore be later combined into a single database …*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point of UUIDs is that it doesn't matter who generates them and there is no state you need to worry about (i.e. the chance that 2 separate systems both generating random UUIDs happen to generate identical UUIDs, rounds down to zero). Hence, let MySQL generate it. Or let java generate it. Whatever is more convenient. There is no inherent drawback to either form.